# How to deleting SMS in android studio

Tags: java, android, permissions, sdk, sms

I can get sms from the phone
I want to delete the last message from the phone.
How can i do that?
Can u help me? Thanks.

The code I use to for pull SMS:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] smsm = null;
    String sms_str = "";
    String id = Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);


    if (bundle != null) {
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        smsm = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < smsm.length; i++) {
            smsm[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            sms_str += "SMS: ";
            sms_str += smsm[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            sms_str += "\n\r";
            String number= smsm[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            Intent smsIntent = new Intent("otp");
            smsIntent.putExtra("message", sms_str);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(smsIntent);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

On modern Android devices, only the default SMS app (as set by the user, there's no way to set this programmatically on a non-rooted phone) can delete SMSes.  If you're trying to delete it because your app uses SMS to communicate, look into other forms of communication.

Comment: The example code above shows the incoming sms
I want to delete it just the same

Comment: @MustafaKemal  Unless you're the default SMS app that the user set, you can't.  This was a security change made in Android 4.4 or so (would have to look up the exact version) to prevent apps from just deleting SMSes.  If you are that app, you can delete it from the content provider.